# SVG external spritemap instances not viewable in local environment

Tags: svg

I am using SVG fragment identifiers from an external spritemap to display SVG icons. This is working just fine on a web server.

However, when working locally, the SVG icons do not display. If I run my page using AMPPS (MAMP equivalent) on localhost, they display fine.

spritemap.svg fragment:

```
<symbol id="icon-close" viewBox="10.061 10.712 105.601 105.601">
    <line fill="none" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="12.536" y1="13.187" x2="113.187" y2="113.838" />
    <line fill="none" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="113.187" y1="13.187" x2="12.536" y2="113.838" />
</symbol>
```

HTML:

```
<svg class="icon icon-line" title="close" role="image">
    <use xlink:href="pathto/spritemap.svg#icon-close" />
</svg>
```

This is not an SVG issue, more of an environment issue. I am not sure why this displays fine in localhost or on the web, but not when viewing the file directly without a web server.

Comment: On Chrome? Chrome's security model doesn't allow it. You can run with the command line option --allow-file-access-from-files to override this.

Comment: Thank you, yes that works. I had to look up how to do that, but it worked. http://blog.derraab.com/2013/05/30/start-google-chrome-with-local-file-access-on-mac-os-x/

For Safari: http://ccm.net/faq/36342-safari-how-to-enable-local-file-access

Answer (score 0):

As Robert Longson mentioned, I needed to add the --allow-file-access-from-files tag.

Chrome: http://blog.derraab.com/2013/05/30/start-google-chrome-with-local-file-access-on-mac-os-x/

For Safari: http://ccm.net/faq/36342-safari-how-to-enable-local-file-access